# A for-loop without a body in C++

Tags: c++

During a test we were asked the following question, What is the C++ program below going to print?.

---

```
for (int j=1;j<=6 ; j++)  {
    for ( int i = 1; i<=j ; i++)
        cout<<i;
    cout<<endl;
}
```

---

So i gave my answer as :

```
            1
            1
            2
            1
            2
            3
            1
            2
            3
            4
            1
            2
            3

            4
            5
            1
            2
            3
            4
            5
            6
```

That is how i understood it. Later on i typed it in the source code, executed the code and the output was surprisingly :

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
```

And then i realised that the inner for loop in the question had no body braces.
So The output of my answer is provided if the code is:

---

```
for (int j=1;j<=6 ; j++)  {
  for ( int i = 1; i<=j ; i++) {
   cout<<i ;
   cout<<endl;}   //Note the opening and closing braces and compare with the one above.;
  }
```

What is the main difference between the two programs regarding how they are executed? 
What happens in the first for loop above in which the inner loop has no body braces.? 
My teacher could not provide me with much assistance, please help.

Comment: lesson to learn: always put braces, even for loops with one statements (especially when they are nested)

Comment: Now that *test* is very similar with some stupid word riddles which rely on badly expressed conditions. Anybody having written it like that in real world coding should have been executed.

Comment: **sigh** I know enough teams where you are forced by stupid style guides to write it this way. Where I hate it most: https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Coding_Style

Comment: I'd like to point out that indenting code is significant. Not to the compiler, but to the reader. For example, to me, the initial code was immediately clear just from the indention. With your code snippet at the end, I had to look twice though because it neither follows any common coding style no is it even internally consistent. Don't do that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't specify the scope of the for loop with {} it will assume one instruction scope.

So this code:

```
for (int j=1;j<=6 ; j++)  {
  for ( int i = 1; i<=j ; i++) 
    cout<<i ;
  cout<<endl;
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
for (int j=1;j<=6 ; j++)  {
      for ( int i = 1; i<=j ; i++) {
        cout<<i ;
      }
      cout<<endl;
    }
```

Same applies to if and other loops. This can be a very hard to find bug sometimes especially if you do something like:

```
if (condition) ;
   do_something();
```

It will do_somethign regardless of the condition. Thats why I personally try to avoid the if/for's without scope.

Hope this helps.

Comment: agreed.  I like to use braces regardless of the number of lines to be executed.  It helps with readability.

Comment: the code I have posted with if actually comes from one of the windows drivers (someone posted "why microsoft drivers are so buggy" with this example)

Comment: That doesn't surprise me that that is in a windows driver.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int j=1;j<=6 ; j++)  {
    for ( int i = 1; i<=j ; i++)
        cout<<i;
        cout<<endl;
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
for (int j=1;j<=6 ; j++)  {
    for ( int i = 1; i<=j ; i++)
    {
        cout<<i;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So if you indent the program it will look something like this:

```
for (int j=1;j<=6 ; j++)  
{
    for ( int i = 1; i<=j ; i++) 
        cout<<i ;
    cout<<endl;
}
```

What you've got going on here is that the cout << i is the ONLY thing that's exectured by teh inner for loop, this is because there's no braces around the inner for loop, so only th enext statement is executed.  It's often done with if statements e.g.

```
if(isValid == true)
    cout << "It's Valid" << endl;
cout << "This isn't part of the if block" << endl;
```

So the outer loop will add the endl.

It's all to do with variable scope. So the scope of i is the inner loop ONLY, whereas the int j, could be used in the inner loop as well as the outer loop.

Hope that helps a little

Answer (score 1):

the inner loop only runs the line

```
cout << i;
```

the line:

```
cout<< endl;
```

is executed as part of the outer loop so the answe is

```
1 
12
123
1234
12345
123456
```

if you don't specify braces for a loop it only executes the next line.

Answer (score 1):

A `for` loop executes a single statement. Now, that can either be a compound statement (which is a group of statements within braces) or a single statement, which is an expression terminated with a semi-colon.

You're code actually has this shape:

```
for (int j=1;j<=6 ; j++)  {
   for ( int i = 1; i<=j ; i++) 
      cout<<i ;
   cout<<endl;
}
```

where the `cout<<i` is the statement attached to the inner `for`. Notice how the outer `for` uses braces (`{` and `}`) to group multiple statements into a compound statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your original code is equivalent to:

```
for (int j=1;j<=6 ; j++)  {
    for ( int i = 1; i<=j ; i++) {
        cout<<i;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**1st Scenario**

```
for(int i=1;i<=10;i++) {
    for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
        cout<<j;
    cout<<endl;
}

for(int i=1;i<=10;i++) {
    for(int j=1;j<=i;j++) {
        cout<<j;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

The code above means the same to the compiler and 
will give a output like
1
12
123
....
Because a ***for loop without braces will consider only one immediate statement under its block***.

**2nd Scenario**
A code like this (mind the space before `i`)

```
for(int i=1;i<=10;i++) {
    for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
        cout<<j;
        cout<<" "<<i;
    cout<<endl;
}
```

would print
1 1
12 2
123 3
1234 4
Because no matter how many statements are there written under a for loop without braces, ***it will only consider 1 statement only under its block***, and i gave the space before `i` only to explain that the for loop without braces finishes executing the immediate next first then terminates the loop

Hope it helps, any more query? Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

If to remove braces in this code snippet

```
for (int j=1;j<=6 ; j++)  {
    for ( int i = 1; i<=j ; i++)
        cout<<i;
        cout<<endl;
}
```

then the outer loop will be equivalent to the following

```
for (int j=1;j<=6 ; j++)  {
    for ( int i = 1; i<=j ; i++)
        cout<<i;
}
cout<<endl;
```

Or that is the same

```
for (int j=1;j<=6 ; j++)  {
    for ( int i = 1; i<=j ; i++) {
        cout<<i;
    }
}
cout<<endl;
```

and the output will look like

```
112123123412345123456
```

From the C++ Standard (6.5 Iteration statements)

> 2 The substatement in an iteration-statement implicitly defines a
>   block scope (3.3) which is entered and exited each time through the
>   loop. **If the substatement in an iteration-statement is a single
>   statement and not a compound-statement, it is as if it was rewritten
>   to be a compound-statement containing the original statement.** [
>   Example:

```
while (--x >= 0)
int i;
```

can be equivalently rewritten as

```
while (--x >= 0) {
int i;
}
```

The example has the same sense if to substitute the while iteration statement for the for iteration statement.

Comment: Uhm, no. `cout<<endl;` is still part of the outer loop, so the output is printed on many lines, not on just one. The OP's post has been edited to better show this.

Comment: @Fabio Turati  I think there is clear written in my post how the loop will look if to remove the braces.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I was confused by the wording, and by the fact that most answers focus on showing the result of having/not having the braces in the **inner** loop, whereas you have taken the opposite route. I still think it is a little confusing, but you are right, your code is correct.